# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am trying to install a theme locally but when I go to do it I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\royalestate\slider.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  369184  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0007  372840  require( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17
3   1.3620  21193256    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-includes\template-loader.php'   ) ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   1.3635  21212432    include( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\royalestate\homepage.php' ) ..\template-loader.php:47
5   1.4038  21296984    include( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\royalestate\slider.php' )   ..\homepage.php:12
```

If my problem lies in the slider code then that is below, but I don't think there should be as I installed it fresh out of the box.

```
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php $slider_ctr = 0; foreach($slides as $num => $slide) : if ($slider_ctr < 5) : $image_aq = aq_resize($slide['src'], 100, 73, true);
                ?><li data-thumb="<?php echo aq_resize($slide['src'], 100, 73, true) ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $slide['link'] ?>"><img alt="" src="<?php echo aq_resize($slide['src'], 676, 290, true) ?>"/></a>
                    <div class="flex-caption">
                        <p><?php echo $slide['title'] ?></p>
                        <p><strong><?php echo $slide['caption'] ?></strong></p>
                    </div>
                </li><?php
                $slider_ctr++; endif; endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your help would be much appreciated. 
Cheers,
Rags

Answer (score 2):

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

this is issued when a `non-array` object or value is passed in to foreach loop.

You might want to **var_dump($slides);** and see what it holds. It most likely holds a **boolean false** or **null** value.

Before using foreach loop I would check if **$slides** is an array

```
 if (is_array($slides)) {
   foreach($slides as $slide) {
     ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately I'm fully noob so have no idea where to find that var_dump($slides); bit. I usually just edit normal HTML and this is my first foray into WP. Once I find that var_dump, shall I change the value around there to true? Thanks :D

Comment: no var_dump just prints out the full values of an object. you dont want to use var_dump when deploying your website. Then to avoid error message do if (is_array($slides)).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, put

```
if(is_array($slides))
```

before the foreach

Comment: Nope didn't help :( Have mailed the creator hopefully get a result . Thanks anyway guys :D